# PHP echo in echo

Tags: php, string, echo

I have a string that looks like this:

```
<center>
    <div style="margin-top: 10px; margin-bottom: 10px; font-size: 20px; color: #000; font-weight: bold;">
        <?php echo strlen(file_get_contents('test.txt')); ?> Applications Sent
    </div>
</center>
```

However, I want to echo this with an if statment. For example:

```
if ($test == '') { 
    echo '<center><div style="margin-top: 10px; margin-bottom: 10px; font-size: 20px; color: #000; font-weight: bold;"><?php echo strlen(file_get_contents("test.txt")); ?> Applications Sent</div></center>';
}
```

The problem is that this will not work, because the original string already has an echo in it. How can I get around this?

Comment: Why aren't you escaping the single quotes inside the string?

Answer (score 6):

In order to achieve this you should concatenate your strings. In this case you have two strings surrounding a function - but that function returns a string so it is perfectly valid to just concatenate them all together.

```
if ($test == '') { 
    echo '<center><div style="margin-top: 10px; margin-bottom: 10px; font-size: 20px; color: #000; font-weight: bold;">' . strlen(file_get_contents("test.txt")) . ' Applications Sent</div></center>';
}
```